# Como definir uma cor usando o elemento <Color/> do Xamarin Forms dentro de um ResourceDictionary

Tags: xml, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xaml

Olá, estou seguindo [esse tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/easy-app-theming-with-xamarin-forms-styles/) e, partindo do que ele mostra junto com a documentação do Xamarin.Forms, eu posso criar um Resource dictionary da seguinte forma:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="App.Assets.Colors">

    <Color x:Key="TestBlue">Blue</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TestRed">Red</Color>
    <Color x:Key="TestGreen">Green</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

E com o `ResourceDictionary` criado, eu posso chamá-lo em qualquer componente, inclusive nos resources globais da aplicação assim:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="App.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Colors.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

O problema é que quando vou compilar a aplicação para poder usar essa Resource em algum lugar do código, o mesmo me traz um erro descrito:

**The type 'Color' does not support direct content.**

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu ja fiz isso em Windows Presentation Forms e gostaria de poder flexibilizar melhor o controle de variáveis e extender estilos de uma forma simples e dinâmica mas tem um bom tempo que não pesquiso e não acho como fazer...

Comment: Pode fornecer um exemplo de onde está tentando usar a cor?

Comment: O problema não é usar a cor, é conseguir declará-la e importá-la no Xamarin. Eu fiz o mesmo código que no Wpf e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Tentou ativar a compilação de xaml? Colocar `<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>` antes de abrir a tag de `ResourceDictionary` no seu xaml?

Comment: Não, não tentei... Pra falar a verdade eu nem sabia qua existia isso ... Vou dar uma olhada amanhã e confirmo aqui se deu

Comment: @LeandroLuk, o seu código deveria funcionar... há algumas diferenças entreo XAML do wpf e do xamarin.forms, mas essa não é uma delas... Consegiu fazer funcionar habilitando a compilaçãodo XAML?

Answer (score -1):

O ResourceDictionary é para você criar recursos compartilhados como você disse, mas neste caso você está tentando informar um arquivo xml para especificar as cores. A utilização correta seria como abaixo.

Coloca o código abaixo no App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary MergedWith="light:LightThemeResources">
      <!-- Cores compartilhadas -->
      <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#F4F6FA</Color>
      <Color x:Key="TextColor">#722881</Color>

      <!-- FONT SIZE -->

      <OnPlatform
          x:Key="MidMediumSize"
          x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
          iOS="12"
          Android="14"
          WinPhone="14"/>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Nas suas páginas xaml vc pode usar os resources da seguinte forma:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource MidMediumSize}" FontAttributes = "Bold" TextColor = "{StaticResource TextColor}" />
```

Comment: A pergunta é exatamente sobre a tag `<Color />` e essa resposta não resolve o problema no Xamarin Forms porque a forma que ela é implementada é diferente de WPF (que é a forma que eu coloquei no exemplo). Em relação ao ResourceDictionary, eu pretendo usá-lo conforme o exemplo acima, separando cada importância em um arquivo e importando-os no App.xaml.

Comment: Mas essa solução não é para WPF. Eu retirei esta solução de um projeto Xamarin.Forms em que trabalho. Você está tentando colocar um arquivo xaml como um resource dictionary, por isso está dando erro.